# Is it Pythonic to have a module named `functions`?

Tags: python, naming

I have a Django project. All the apps are separated nicely. Each apps often have functions that are used across the apps. Currently I place them in module named `wrappers` (for wrapping django/built-in/3rd party functions) and `shortcuts` (for wrapping django/built-in/3rd party functions with hardcoded arguments).

For pure functions, where should I put them? currently I put them in `__init__` files in the top level of each apps. So to import them I simply call `from project.app import function`. Is that Pythonic or create a module named `functions` inside each apps is more Pythonic?

As far as I remember, I never import a module named 'functions' though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine a carpenter with lots of tools on her workbench. How could she organize these tools and parts? Probably, by type or application: hammers and pliers, files and saws all have their place. That sounds sensible. But what if she organizes them by colour: all tools with a yellow grip go over there, all tools with a wooden grip go in this drawer. That is also a legitimate organization scheme, but it makes it difficult to find the tools you're working with. Python packages are also a kind of tool set.

Your categorization scheme wrappers/shortcuts/functions describes how the functions in those packages were created. It does not describe how those functions will actually be used. So when I need to find some function, I have to look in all of these packages and then maybe the Django documentation to find a suitable function. I don't know in advance whether I am looking for a pure function you wrote or a wrapped function.

It is better to organize your code by topic and by purpose. For example, you may have written a couple of functions that help with input validation. Don't spread them over many packages, but organize them as a `project.myapp.validation` package.